# How to avoid duplicate data in Django Template

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I have this piece of code :

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block page_title %}Manage Staff{% endblock page_title %}

{% block content %}

<section class="content">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h3 class="card-title">Manage All Staff</h3>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.card-header -->
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <table id="example2" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>SN</th>
                                    <th>Full Name</th>
                                    <th>Email</th>
                                    <th>Course</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                {% for staff in allStaff %}
                                <tr>
                                    <td>-</td>
                                    <td>{{staff.last_name}}, {{staff.first_name}}</td>
                                    <td>{{staff.email}}</td>
                                    <td>{{staff.course.name}}</td>
                                </tr>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
{% endblock content %}
```

The block `page_title` is used to display the current page in `base.html`.
My question is, how can I avoid repeating the text "Manage Staff" ?
Is there a way to display the block `page_title` in this current file ?
What I earlier tried was passing the value from my `views.py` file, so I wanna be sure I am doing the right thing

Comment: Will Manage Staff always be same? You can always set default block value in base that you extend ( you can think about blocks as object methods that you can override)

Comment: @iklinac For another page, it is 'Manage Student'. I do not like the idea of having to repeat same data. Perhaps I should pass the value from my view?

Comment: you can always pass it from context for sure

Comment: @iklinac Thanks, I will do that.